# Batch Export selection of PDF files with no user interaction?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'm using Acrobat Pro DC (macOS) and have set up an Action to Export PDF to DOCX format.

I have specified the files I wish to include.

However, I have to click the following buttons for each file:

1. Proceed
2. Export (defaults)
3. Recent Folder (same for all files)
4. Save (defaults)

Is there a way to not have to be present whilst it does these conversions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is: using JavaScript in an Action List.

This is what I ended up with...

JavaScript:

```
var newfile = this.documentFileName.replace(/\.pdf$/i, "") +".docx";
this.saveAs(newfile, "com.adobe.acrobat.docx");
```

Action List:

[image]

Works well. i can press Start and then go away and it will do the whole batch without any human input.

The only annoying thing is that the Acrobat window keeps regaining focus between each file, even if I hide it. The workaround for that is to put Acrobat in a Space of its own.